How to get client IP using Moquette MQTT
I would like to collect when a client connects his ip address and port.
@Override
public void onConnect(InterceptConnectMessage msg) {}

InterceptConnectMessage class does not give me ip address information,I am using sprinboot and moquette version 15.

This is a more broad question than just Spring Boot. It is easy to collect the IP of an incoming HTTP request, but whether that is the true IP of the client making the request is a different story. Why do you need it?

@ryanwebjackson actually it is in a MQTT request the subtraction of the ip address, I need it to return it in a message to a topic

@javier-matute-barragán the short answer is: please open an feature request to the Moquette project https://github.com/moquette-io/moquette/.
Long answer:
Moquette could grab the remote IP from the incoming connection, but that wouldn't necessarily be the originating host, maybe because in the middle there is a proxy or similar. I would suggest that each client discover his external IP, and using user-properties communicate down the broker (only in MQTT 5) and that point the InterceptConnectMessage would contains also such user properties, and for this you also need to create a feature request.
